# How to read each char from string NASM assembly 64bit linux

Tags: linux, assembly, char, x86-64, nasm

I have a 64bit NASM assembly assignment to capitalize (all letters should be lowercase,except those which are at the beginning of the sentence) letters of input text. I'm totally new to assembler and I can't find anywhere how I should read each char from string incrementally, when I read the text like this:

```
section .data

prompt      db  "Enter your text: ", 10
length      equ $ - prompt
text        times 255 db 0
textsize    equ $ - text    

section .text
global main
main:
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, prompt
    mov     rdx, length
    syscall         ;print prompt

    mov     rax, 0
    mov     rdi, 0
    mov     rsi, text
    mov     rdx, textsize
    syscall         ;read text input from keyboard




exit:
    mov     rax, 60
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Also, I'm not sure how to find out when the text is over, so I could know when I have to exit the program. Should I do some operations with text size or there is some king of special symbol which shows the EOL? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: `sys_read` (syscall 0) returns the number of characters read in `rax` IIRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After returning from sys_read (syscall rax=0) RAX register should contain the number of characters actually has been read. Notice, that in Linux, sys_read will return when /n is accepted, even if there is more place in the buffer provided.

Then organize a loop from 0 to RAX and process each character the way you want:

```
        mov    byte ptr [text+rax], 0  ; make the string zero terminated for future use.

        mov    rcx, rax  ; rcx will be the character counter.
        mov    rsi, text ; a pointer to the current character. Start from the beginning.

process_loop:
        mov    al, [rsi]   ; is it correct NASM syntax?

       ; here process al, according to your needs...
       ; .....

       inc    rsi
       dec    rcx
       jnz    process_loop
```

The above code can be optimized of course, for example to use string instructions or loop instructions, but IMO, this way is better for a beginner.

Comment: +1, but the `Loop` instruction is the opposite of optimization.

Comment: @Johan - not always. For example on 80386 it is faster. Also, it depends on "what optimization" - there is a size optimization as well.

Comment: Correct, the 386 was the **last** processor for which `loop` is faster. The 486 was introduced in 1989.

Comment: @Johan - you missed "optimization for size" point. IMHO, for the modern processors, only size optimization is reasonable.

Comment: A Modern processor fetches 16 bytes per cycle (on AMD it's 32). Loop saves 1 byte. Loop is a microcode instruction, costs extra time to decode so you lose +/- 6 uops idling (8 on Haswell). Hardly an optimization. Even worse `loop` leaves a false dependency on the flags register so the delay may be even more.

Comment: @Johan - it is matter of choice. For me 1024 x 1byte is a KB. And `lodsb` saves 2 more bytes or even 4. ;)

Comment: But why save the space, in and of itself it serves no purpose. Saving time (given a tight enough loop). `lodsb` is even more(!) inefficient. Obviously you're janking my chain. Well played!